# Start learning Asynchronous coding for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I didn't ask how to learn JavaScript/Ajax/JQuery and god knows what else is out there! =)

I just need to know the best choice and how to start learning it for adding a desktop experience to my web application

To make it easy for you to help me guys, these are the points or criteria that I think I will need to have in the choice your going to suggest :

- I don't want an easy solution that will miss up my application's stability and maintainability
- I want something implicitly powerful but still gives you the control like writing in asp.net
- I don't want an asynchronous website that will back-stab my visitors' experience with the slow browsing and lagging

Thanks for your help in advance and if I said anything that sounded non-sense to you , please excuse my ignorance with such technology =)

**Edit**

Trying to think in a loud voice, *how about JQuery ?*

Comment: So you don't want it to be easy, you want something powerful, and you don't want it to be slow. Hate to say it, but it sounds like you need to learn JavaScript... Check out this article though: http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

Comment: @Ikashef what is your requirement , do you want to speed up your website or do you have any issues with your current website. depends upon the context we use asyncrounous coding , if you can tell us your problem in specific we can suggest some solution.

Comment: @siri, Until now there's no problem. I just want to give my visitors the Asynchronous experience. it's pretty good to have some stuff that updates as if it's a desktop application .. like arranging items ASC|DESC or a dropdownlist the trigger another dropdownlist to update it's values .. I don't want to just throw Ajax script manager and some update panels .. I saw articles on that it gives the slowest experience and having the whole page to reload is better than using them .. that's what I saw, if you have another opinion please share it

Comment: @Bryan. I'm sorry If I throw you off with the word powerful I don't want to build a javascript/asynchronous based website .. but you know I don't want something like ajax it's pretty drag and drop it doesn't give you any control and AFAIK behind the scenes it reloads the whole page or maybe worth (there was this article that compares the an Ajax and Ajax-less pages' ViewState)

Comment: The common perception of AJAX is flawed. Asynchronous just means it's happening in the background without blocking anything else from loading. An AJAX request can load an entire page's contents, but it certainly doesn't have to (and most of the time it doesn't). If asynchronous scripts are slower, then why are all the top web applications using them? For example, Twitter (when logged in) is a single page application. Literally EVERYTHING gets loaded asynchronously with JavaScript. It's only slow if you write garbage code, which is why learning JavaScript properly is so important.

Comment: @Bryan +1 for the great blog post. It's the same as writting spaghitti asp.net application and building a neat or patterned applications I agree! .. but which would be good for just making some controls asynchronous like submit buttons (takes the values in the textboxes, dropdownlists, etc and send them to be stored in the database) or have for example a country List that will update the city list depending on the country, etc .. you know? not a one page application but just a better experience for the visitors for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common perception of AJAX is flawed. Asynchronous just means it's happening in the background without blocking anything else from loading. An AJAX request can load an entire page's contents, but it certainly doesn't have to (and most of the time it doesn't).

If asynchronous scripts are slower, then why are all the top web applications using them? For example, Twitter (when logged in) is a single page application. Literally EVERYTHING gets loaded asynchronously with JavaScript. It's only slow if you write garbage code, which is why learning JavaScript properly is so important.

jQuery will most certainly be the easiest to learn due to the huge following, good documentation, and swarms of educational resources online. Pretty much any question you could possibly have about jQuery has been answered on Stack Overflow already.

I would recommend a few good google sessions to learn the best practices of JavaScript though. I've been using jQuery for a couple of years now, but just recently began learning JavaScript. It's amazing how much sense everything will make once you learn the fundamentals of JavaScript.

A few links to get you started:

- [Your New Bible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript)
- [Really top-notch books from O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/javascript/index.html)
- [Daily JS](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html)
- [Yahoo's Developer Center](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/)

Also, something that has helped me out a lot is to follow the best developers. You'll learn more lurking on conversations that you could ever believe.

Comment: Excellent =) .. also if you have some JQuery posts or books that would help from beginner to professional level that would be awesome (Y)